# for loop not incrementing through table of array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I've tested my array separately to make sure it is working and holding all the values and it is but for some reason when I run it through my for loop it just prints out 10.95 in 3 rows and 3 columns I don't understand why it isn't pull the rest of the values from my table.

Here is the assignment:

> Write, compile, and run a C++ program to input the following values into an array named prices: 10.95, 16.32, 12.15, 8.22, 15.98, 26.22, 13.54, 6.45, and 17.59 After the data has been entered, have your program display the values in 3 rows and 3 columns.

Here is the code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int COLS = 3;
const int ROWS = 3;

int main()
{
    const int num_items = 9;
    float prices[num_items];

    cout << "Enter the prices of your " << num_items << " items: ";
    cin >> prices[0];
    cin >> prices[1];
    cin >> prices[2];
    cin >> prices[3];
    cin >> prices[4];
    cin >> prices[5];
    cin >> prices[6];
    cin >> prices[7];
    cin >> prices[8];

    float table[ROWS][COLS] = {{prices[0], prices[1], prices[2]},
                                {prices[3], prices[4], prices[5]},
                                {prices[6], prices[7], prices[8]}};

    cout << "The prices you have entered are:\n";

    for (int x = 0; x < ROWS; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < COLS; y++)
        {
            cout << setw(6) << table[ROWS][COLS] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return0;
}
```

Comment: `table[ROWS][COLS]` --> `table[x][y]`. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: It's time to learn about `for` before your program collapses under the weight of all that repeated repeating repetition. Having fewer lines of code often means bugs are more obvious because there's fewer places for them to hide.

Comment: Consider reporting more info ... how about changing 'cout << setw(6) << table[ROWS][COLS] << " "; ' to perhaps something like: cout << setw(6) << table[ROWS][COLS] << " " << ROWS << " " << COLS << std::endl;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cout << setw(6) << table[ROWS][COLS] << " ";
```

should be

```
cout << setw(6) << table[x][y] << " ";
```

Comment: thank you so much I have been looking at this for like 20 minutes trying to figure out why

Comment: ***I have been looking at this for like 20 minutes trying to figure out why***  My advice is to learn how to use your debugger. What I mean by that is single step through the code looking at the variables at each step.